# after gradle build success, class not found exception while running spring boot application

Tags: gradle, configuration

I have created spring boot application using Gradle but after successfully building the application when I am trying to run the application it gives me the main class not found an exception.

I am building an application using the below command:
.\gradlew clean build

The build is getting success. But when I try to run the application as a spring boot application then I am getting the error.

Error: Could not find or load main class com.abc.ccs.CommunityApplication

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootjar {
    baseName = 'create-community'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.26'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino', version: '3.0.6'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
}

jar {
   manifest {
       attributes(
               "Main-Class": "com.abc.ccs.CommunityApplication"
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: Here's how you configure the main class: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class. But the jar task should be disabled anyway. What is the exact and complete exception stack trace?

Comment: Were you able to get around this? I am facing the same issue.